# How to modify several textviews in the same row of a listview

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a ListView with a custom row wich has 2 TextViews. I have made my own Adapter and it's working fine with my list. Now, I want the user to input 2 texts and then insert a new row (with user's inputs) in my ListView. I've tried with add method but I'm getting UnsupportedOperationException. Do I have to override add method also? if so, what do I need to do in it? Thank you.

I'm going to paste a fragment of the code. Let me know if you need further information.

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatItems>{

Context context;
int textViewResourceId;
ChatItems[] objects;


public ChatAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ChatItems[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChatHolder holder = null;


    if(row == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater =  ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, null);

    holder = new ChatHolder();
    holder.user = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
    holder.msg = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textText);

    row.setTag(holder);

    }else
        holder = (ChatHolder) row.getTag();


    ChatItems items = objects[position];
    holder.msg.setText(items.msg);
    holder.user.setText(items.user);


    return row;

}
static class ChatHolder{
    TextView user;
    TextView msg;
}
```

}

```
public class ChatItems {

String user;
String msg;

public ChatItems(String user, String msg){
    this.user = user;
    this.msg = msg;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add another items to your `ArrayAdapter` use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` as your back-end data holder. If you are using `Array`, than `ArrayAdapter` will use `List` internally which can't be modified later.

Remove `objects` field from your `ChatAdapter`.

Rewrite your constructor like

```
public ChatAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ChatItems> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}
```

to get the item in `getView()` use `ChatItems items = getItem(position)` instead of `ChatItems items = objects[position];`

And finally create your adapter like `adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, R.layout.chat_item, new ArrayList<ChatItems>());`

Comment: Thank you for your quick ansers! You both were right (Sa Dec). I was using a simple array instead of an ArrayList. Once changed it works properly.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you used an immutable list, hence it raised [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) when you tried to add element(s) to the list. Consider using `ArrayList` or something mutable.

If you can provide logcat then it will help (us) more.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

"
However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

"

You need to play more with the adapter than the list view itself, the list view uses the Adapter after-all.

That doc should contain all the information you need.
Good luck! Remember to post your solution.